# DevIL/OpenIL isn't loading alpha channel

Tags: c++, devil

I am having an issue where the `.png` image that I want to load as a byte array using DevIL is not having an alpha channel.

A complete black image is also appearing as having alpha channel values as 0.

This is my image loading function:

```
DevILCall(ilGenImages(1, &m_ImageID));
DevILCall(ilBindImage(m_ImageID));

ASSERT("Loading image: " + path);

DevILCall(ilLoadImage(path.c_str()));

GraphicComponents::Image image(
    ilGetData(),
    ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
    ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BITS_PER_PIXEL)
);

return image;
```

The `Image` object I am using is as follows:

```
struct Image
{
    ILubyte * m_Image;
    const unsigned int m_Height;
    const unsigned int m_Width;
    const unsigned int m_BPP;

    Image(ILubyte imageData[ ], unsigned int height, unsigned int width, unsigned int bpp);
    ~Image();
};
```

And this is how I am printing out the image data for now:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < image->m_Height*image->m_Width*4; i+=4)
{
    LOG("Red:");
    LOG((int) image->m_Image[i]);
    LOG("Green:");
    LOG((int) image->m_Image[i+1]);
    LOG("Blue:");
    LOG((int) image->m_Image[i+2]);
    LOG("Alpha:");
    LOG((int) image->m_Image[i+3]);
}
```

I also tried using the `ilTexImage()` to format the loaded image to `RGBA` format but that also doesn't seem to work. The printing loop starts reading garbage values when I change the maximum value of the loop variable to 4 times the number of pixels in the image.

The image is also confirmed to have an alpha channel.
What might be going wrong here?

EDIT: `ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP)` is returning 3, which should mean RGB for now. When I use the `ilTexImage()` to force 4 channels, then `ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP)` returns 4 but I still see garbage values popping up at the std output

Comment: Looks like you're setting both the `GraphicComponents::Image` width and height parameters with `ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT)`. What if the image isn't square?

Comment: That's embarrassing. It seems it's just a bug. Changed it to `IL_IMAGE_WIDTH`, but the problem still persists. I can see paint.net showing 0, 0, 0, 255 all over the image but the output from the program shows alpha as 0 and some garbage values in between

Comment: It's been years since I touched DevIL so I can't be much help. You could try loading the image with `ilLoad(IL_PNG, path.c_str())` to bypass the automatic file type detection in case there's something wrong with the image header.

Comment: I tried the `ilLoad()` function but the problem persists, anyway thanks for paying attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by a simple `ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)` call after loading the image.

I suppose DevIL loads the image in `RGB` mode with unsigned byte values by default and to use otherwise, you need to convert the loaded image using `ilConvertImage()`.